# pausesubsections causes also subsubsections to be paused

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, pause

I'm creating a longer presentation using beamer and I'm using 'evil' subsubsections. I'm using the pausesubsections option for the tableofcontents. The problem is that not only the subsections get paused, but also each subsubsection, which is annoying. How can I get rid of this?

Here is a minimum working example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \tableofcontents[pausesubsections]
\end{frame}

\section{Test}

\subsection{Test}

\subsubsection{Test}

\begin{frame}
    Test
\end{frame}

\subsubsection{Test}

\begin{frame}
    Test
\end{frame}

\subsection{Test}

\subsubsection{Test}

\begin{frame}
    Test
\end{frame}

\subsubsection{Test}

\begin{frame}
    Test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could patch the command `\beamer@subsubsectionintoc` and remove the line responsible for adding the `\pause` macro.

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\beamer@subsubsectionintoc}{\ifbeamer@pausesubsections\pause\fi}{}{}{}
\makeatother
```